# Do inotify watches automatically stop when a program ends?

Tags: linux, c, inotify

Per `man 7 inotify`, there are a limited number of `inotify` instances (`/proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_instances`) and watches (`/proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches`).  If `inotify` is set up using `inotify_init1` and `inotify_add_watch`, and the program ends without calling `inotify_rm_watch` and without closing the inotify file descriptor, does the kernel stop these instances/watches, or will they continue to count toward the limiting number of instances/watches?

Comment: When the PROCESS exits, all its file descriptor is closed.

Comment: But notice that fd is closed doesn't mean the open file description is closed, the /sys interface report this number, not the number of fd, read APUE.